# Cannot load from object array because "this.decisionToDFA" is null

Tags: antlr, antlr4

**Update 2)**:- It is as if the **static block** of code at the bottom of the TestLexer.java is not running on my side.

I change the **static block**

```
static { 
         _decisionToDFA = new DFA[_ATN.getNumberOfDecisions()];
        for (int i = 0; i < _ATN.getNumberOfDecisions(); i++) {
            _decisionToDFA[i] = new DFA(_ATN.getDecisionState(i), i);
        }

}
```

to a **static metod** which I called **makeDecisionToDFA()**

```
protected static final DFA[] _decisionToDFA = makeDecisionToDFA();

private static DFA[] makeDecisionToDFA() {
        DFA[] decisionToDFA = new DFA[_ATN.getNumberOfDecisions()];
        for (int i = 0; i < _ATN.getNumberOfDecisions(); i++) {
            decisionToDFA[i] = new DFA(_ATN.getDecisionState(i), i);
        }
                return decisionToDFA;
    }
```

The exception then moves to another location:-

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "this.decisionToDFA" is null
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ParserATNSimulator.adaptivePredict(ParserATNSimulator.java:341)
at com.example.test.TestParser.statements(TestParser.java:209)
at com.example.test.TestParser.parse(TestParser.java:154)
at Main.main(Main.java:31)

---

**Updated 1)**:- I have added TestLexer.g4 and TestParser.g4

---

I am using Antlr 4.9.2 to generate a Java parser and lexer.

My java version is:-
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.1+9-18)

I am getting the following exception when I run my program.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "this.decisionToDFA" is null
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.LexerATNSimulator.match(LexerATNSimulator.java:109)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Lexer.nextToken(Lexer.java:141)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.fetch(BufferedTokenStream.java:169)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.sync(BufferedTokenStream.java:152)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.setup(BufferedTokenStream.java:254)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.BufferedTokenStream.lazyInit(BufferedTokenStream.java:249)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream.LT(CommonTokenStream.java:92)
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser.enterRule(Parser.java:628)
at com.examlpe.test.TestParser.parse(MyParser.java:142)
at Main.main(Main.java:37)
```

I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong; I might be missing something.
I would highly appreciate it if somebody can point me in the right direction.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CharStream stream = CharStreams.fromFileName(args[0]);
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(stream);
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
        parser.setBuildParseTree(true);

        TestParser.ParseContext tree = parser.parse();
    
        ParseTreeWalker walker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        TestListener listener = new TestListener();
        walker.walk(listener, tree);
    }
}
```

---

TestLexer.g4

```
lexer grammar TestLexer;

@header {
package com.example.test;
}

OUTPUT:'output';
PACKAGE:'package';
STRUCT:'struct';
CLASS:'class';

// §3.11 Separators
LPAREN : '(';
RPAREN : ')';
LBRACE : '{';
RBRACE : '}';
LBRACK : '[';
RBRACK : ']';
SEMI : ';';
COMMA : ',';
DOT : '.';

LIST : 'List';
MAP  : 'Map';

ID : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z'| '1'..'9' | '#' | '*' | '<' | '>')+ ;

PACKAGE_NAME : ID ('.' ID)* ;
ANNOTATION_NAME : AT ID ; 

// §3.12 Operators
BACKTICK : '`';
ASSIGN : '=';
GT : '>';
LT : '<';
BANG : '!';
TILDE : '~';
QUESTION : '?';
COLON : ':';
EQUAL : '==';
LE : '<=';
GE : '>=';
NOTEQUAL : '!=';
AND : '&&';
OR : '||';
INC : '++';
DEC : '--';
ADD : '+';
SUB : '-';
MUL : '*';
DIV : '/';
BITAND : '&';
BITOR : '|';
CARET : '^';
MOD : '%';
ARROW : '->';
COLONCOLON : '::';
DOUBEQOATE : '"';


AT : '@';
ELLIPSIS : '...';

WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip
    ;

LINE_COMMENT 
    :   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip
    ;
```

TestParser.g4

```
parser grammar TestParser;

options { tokenVocab=TestLexer; }

@header {
package com.example.test;
}

parse 
    : 
    statements* EOF
    ;

statements 
    : outputDecl
    | packageDecl
    | structDecl
    | classDecl
    ;

outputDecl
    : OUTPUT outputAnnotationDecl*?
    ;
 
packageDecl 
    : PACKAGE PACKAGE_NAME
    ;

outputAnnotationDecl
    : name=ANNOTATION_NAME
    ;

structAnnotationDecl
    : name=ANNOTATION_NAME
    ;

classAnnotationDecl
    : name=ANNOTATION_NAME
    ;

structDecl 
    : structAnnotationDecl*? name=ID STRUCT LBRACE variableDecl+ RBRACE
    ;

variableDecl
    : name=ID type=ID tagsDecl?
    | name=ID LIST GT type=ID LT tagsDecl?
    | name=ID MAP GT type=ID COMMA ID LT tagsDecl?
    ;

tagsDecl
    : BACKTICK (tagDecl*?) BACKTICK
    ;

tagDecl
    :name=ID COLON DOUBEQOATE (vale=ID (COMMA?))+ DOUBEQOATE
    ;

classDecl 
    : classAnnotationDecl*? name=ID CLASS LBRACE (functionDeclType)* RBRACE
    ;

functionDeclType
    : name=ID COLON (functionDecl)*
    ;

functionDecl
    : name=ID LPAREN (functionParameterDecl (COMMA)?)*? RPAREN (COLON returnType=ID)?
    ;

functionParameterDecl
    : name=ID type=ID
    ;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a repo where we could get code to reproduce this?  I've looked at it briefly, and there's not a way (that I can easily see) that the decisionToDFA should not be initialized.  (and nothing is obviously wrong with your code (at a glance))

Comment: I have created a repo at https://github.com/barnardh/test . 
I also do not see something obviously wrong with my code.

Comment: I cloned your repo, generated source (and check that there were no differences using git).  I then ran your main with no errors.  I do notice that your input files were empty.  Were you running them on empty input?

Comment: Thank you Mike Cargal. I created the project in Apache Netbeans 12.4 and this is where i am having issues. I just created a Netbeans 8 project, and move the same code into the new project and it is working as expected.

I will dig deeper. Apache Netbeans 12.4 uses a newer version of Ant.